# How to update child table in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a one to many relationship with two tables, `Parent` with many `Child`.
I create a parent and add children to it. Then I either create it (if it's a new parent) or update it (if it exists already.) When I create it, everything works properly. However, if I update it, the children don't update.

```
using (var Repo = new ParentRepository(context))
{
   var key = new AnnualFormKey(prnt.Year, prnt.UserId);
   if (Repo.Retrieve(key) == null)
   {
       prnt.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
       prnt.CreatedId = 1;
       Repo.Create(prnt);
       Repo.SaveChanges();   //creates parent and children
   }
   else
   {
       prnt.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
       prnt.UpdatedId = 2;
       Repo.Update(prnt);
       Repo.SaveChanges();   //updates parent but not children
   }
}
```

(Note: Update calls `_context.Entry(orginal).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity)`

Is this a problem with my context or do I need to do something else?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I looked this up more in depth and discovered that Entity Framework doesn't actually update complex entities (as in, it won't save the children). There are lots of complicated workarounds, but mine was very simple. I just deleted the existing entity and created it again (using the updated version).

Comment: Just to mention: Unfortunately in most cases you need the "complicated workarounds" because you cannot always delete the old entities since there might be other entities in the DB refering to parent or children with a foreign key constraint or because you want to keep some column values unchanged and only update a few other columns. You had luck in your case :)

Answer (score 1):

Leave out your `Repo.Update(prnt)` call unless you're specifically detaching the object in `Repo.Retrieve`.  It will already be being tracked.

Comment: When I do that it fails to change the parent. Is this a problem with my tracking?

Comment: Can't really tell from the code you've posted there.  If my solution didn't work, then I guess your Repo is doing something more complicated than normal!